# Calculation of $\left(\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: trigonometry

Shouldn't $\left(\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = |\sec(x)|$?
Why does [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/integral-calculator/%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bcos%5E%7B2%7Dx%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%7D) as well as [my professor](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ejbryan/2017T1math317/practiceMT1s/oldMT5solns.PDF) (page one, also below) claim that $\left(\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \sec(x)$, which can be negative? Also, the length of a vector cannot be negative... isn't it?

[image]

Comment: You are correct that $\sqrt{x^2} \neq x$ otherwise $1 = \sqrt{(-1)^2} =-1$. Indeed, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. However, if $x\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ then Symbolab and your professor are correct as  .

Comment: Symbolab is not correct as I did not specify the domain. It might be a glitch that they definitely need to be aware of. However, my prof was right because of the domain. Thank you so much for saving me from this irrational madness!

Comment: Congrats to you for analysing such details. They are important! And they can kill your proof if you omit them.

Comment: you are right but for $t=\frac \pi 4$ we have $|\cos(t)|=\cos(t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $\sqrt{x^2} \neq x$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$. Otherwise, we would have absurdity like $1 = \sqrt{1}=\sqrt{(-1)^2} =-1$. For $x\in\Bbb R$ we indeed have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. However, we have $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ for all $x\geq 0$.

Hence, as you professor seems to assume that $t\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, his claim that $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}}=\sec(t)$ is correct. Indeed for $t\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, we have $\cos(t)\geq 0$.

Comment: Thank you! Will accept the answer in a few seconds when it lets me.